# phoenix framework how to set default values in Ecto model

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to set default values for a model in Phoenix Framework, I have tried:

```
  def new(conn, _params) do

    user = get_session(conn, :user)
    if is_nil user do
        user = Repo.get_by(User, name: "guest")
        conn = put_session(conn, :user, user)
    end

    changeset = Module.changeset(%Module{})

    changeset
    |> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:user, user)
    |> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:version, "0.0.0")
    |> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:visibility, "public")

    render(conn, "new.html", user: user, changeset: changeset)
  end
```

How do I set default values in the model so they appear when new.html is rendered?

BTW, here is my default changeset function.  I couldn't figure out how to use it?  I'm assuming use a Ecto.changeset.put_change in the pipeline after the cast?

```
  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways depending on your changeset function (which you haven't provided here.)

You could do:

```
changeset = Module.changeset(%Module{user: user, version: "0.0.0", visibility: "public"})
```

Another option is to pass the parameters to your changeset function:

```
changeset = Module.changeset(%Module{}, %{user: user, version: "0.0.0", visibility: "public"})
```

**However** it is important to note that your version with the `put_change/3` function will also work, if you bind the result of your pipeline:

Change:

```
changeset = Module.changeset(%Module{})

changeset
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:user, user)
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:version, "0.0.0")
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:visibility, "public")
```

To:

```
changeset =
  Module.changeset(%Module{})
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:user, user)
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:version, "0.0.0")
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:visibility, "public")
```

Another option is to set the default at the database level in your migration. If you look at the `:default` option of [Ecto.Migration.add/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#add/3) you will see how to do this.

Comment: sweet, thanks!  Do you think it would be better in the changeset function (i.e. in the model instead of the controller)?  Maybe this would be the better way?

Comment: It depends on the use case. If you only want the defaults set when presenting the user with the new form then I'd go with the first option I suggested. If you are using this in several places then have a custom changeset function. If you want it every time a new model of this type is created then use the database for default values.

Comment: awesome, I have used the database default values, this is what I wanted all along, but didn't know existed :-)